# GWT issue : Invoking Linker Cross-Site-Iframe Ignoring the following script tags in the gwt.xml file

Tags: java, xml, iframe, gwt

I am trying to compile an application using the 'GWT Super Dev Mode'. But, I end up having the following

```
Ignoring the following script tags in the gwt.xml file
sc/modules/ISC_Core.js
sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js
sc/modules/ISC_Containers.js
sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js
sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js
sc/modules/ISC_RichTextEditor.js
sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js
sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js
sc/skins/Enterprise/load_skin.js
```

when I use this inside my gwt.xml file.

```
<set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE' />
```

But, my index.html file when viewed in a browser provides me a blank white screen.

Answer (score 1):

The `<script>` elements in gwt.xml files are ignored with the xsiframe linker; you have to put `<script>` elements in your HTML host page instead.